# Can I call a different init method with UICollectionViews dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

In the .h file of `UICollectionView` a comment says:

// If a class is registered, it will be instantiated via alloc/initWithFrame:

Is there a way that I can have it call a custom init method?

Answer (score 0):

How about [cell configureForData:data] right after you dequeue it? You probably need to re-configure the data on dequeued cells, anyway.

Suppose there is a way that you can have it call a custom init method, you wouldn't pass anything to the custom init method by dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:, so setting up the data should be separate from the init method.

Comment: If I did have a way to call a custom init method, of course I would want to be able to pass in data.